# Javacard: ATR and Protocol change

Tags: reverse-engineering, smartcard, javacard, pcsc, gemalto

I am doing reverse engineering to an smart card with a logic analyzer. I made the applet to respond just like the original SC but do not work.
After a further analysis I found 3 issues:

1-ATR: need to change the ATR

2-ATR the communication protocol: I do not know why but the original smart card is not sending the ATR like the standard (in the standard: even parity bit) but it is transmitted with no parity bit

3-PTS: after the ATR I need to set the communication protocol to T=0 with a baudrate: 210526 and not parity(clk=6MHz).

I know that 1 and 3 are possible but i do not know who to do it and I really do not know if the second issue is possible to solve.

I have Gemalto IDcore30 Cards. I also have a Gemalto IDbridge CT30, but not even can read the ATR of the original because of the parity bit difference it can not read the ATR.

Any link or help will be very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about the frequency of your logic analyzer and the card? I think you must to set the logic analyzer frequency 5MHz!

Comment: It can work with 6Mhz or 5MHz clock